# Filtering for Multiple Fields in Object Array in Javascript/Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have the following array:

PeopleList

```
[ {id:1, name:"Brian", status:"active"}, {id:2, name:"Mary", status:"active"},
  {id:3, name:"John", status:"pending"}, {id:4, name:"Steph", status:"pending"},
 {id:5, name:"Peter", status:"inactive"}
]
```

statusList

```
[ 'active', 'pending']
```

I want to filter the object array to only the statusList so I did the following:

```
var filteredPeople  =PeopleList.map(person => {
  for (var i=0; i<=statusList.length; i++){
    if(statusList[i] == person.active)
        return {...person};
  }
});
```

While the person objects return correctly, I also get "undefined" for objects that didn't pass the conditional statement.

So my result is:

```
   [object, object, object,object, undefined ]
```

How can I make it so that if the conditional does not pass, I remove that object from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `map` you should use `filter` for filtering array. You can also use `includes`.

```js
var data = [ {id:1, name:"Brian", status:"active"}, {id:2, name:"Mary", status:"active"},
  {id:3, name:"John", status:"pending"}, {id:4, name:"Steph", status:"pending"},
 {id:5, name:"Peter", status:"inactive"}
]
var statusList = [ 'active', 'pending']

var result = data.filter(e => statusList.includes(e.status))
console.log(result)
```

With ES5 and older versions you can use `indexOf` instead of `includes`.

```js
var data = [ {id:1, name:"Brian", status:"active"}, {id:2, name:"Mary", status:"active"},
  {id:3, name:"John", status:"pending"}, {id:4, name:"Steph", status:"pending"},
 {id:5, name:"Peter", status:"inactive"}
]
var statusList = [ 'active', 'pending']

var result = data.filter(function(e) {
  return statusList.indexOf(e.status) != -1
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var statusList = [];

var PeopleList = [

  { id: 1, name: "Brian", status: "active" },
  { id: 2, name: "Mary", status: "active" },
  { id: 3, name: "John", status: "pending" },
  { id: 4, name: "Steph", status: "pending" },
  { id: 5, name: "Peter", status: "inactive" }

];

for (var counter = 0; counter < PeopleList.length; counter++)
{

statusList.push(PeopleList[counter].status);

document.write(PeopleList[counter].status + "<br />");
}

// Here is your Status array
console.log(statusList);

// loop through all elements in your javascript status array and print them out
for (var i = 0; i < statusList.length; i++)
{

    document.write("<strong>" + statusList[i] + "<br />");
}
```